# Problema de cálculo con Arrays

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en Java y estoy intentando solucionar el siguiente problema:

Quiero determinar cuantos pasajeros quedan en un tren al llegar al fin de su trayecto teniendo en cuenta los pasajeros que suben y bajan en cada estacion. Por este motivo, la función recibe un vector de 2D donde cada posición corresponde a una estación/parada. Cada par de elementos corresponde al nombre de pasajeros que suben (posicion 0) y pasajeros que bajan (posicion 1). Por ejemplo, tendriamos el siguiente vector:

```
[[6,0] [8,2] [1,2]]
```

En la primera estación suben 6 pasajeros y bajan 0. En la segunda estación suben 8 pasajeros y bajan 2. En la última estación suben 1 pasajeros y bajan 2. El resultado debería ser 11 pasajeros en el tren.

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
public static int finalJourneyPassengers(int[][] stops) {
    // Inicializamos la variable pasajeros en el tren
    int passatgersTren = 0;

    // Recorremos la matriz donde i corresponde a la estación y j a las columnas (pasajeros que bajan o suben)
    for (int i=0; i < stops.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            // Los pasajeros en el tren son los que suben - los que bajan.
            passatgersTren = stops[i][0] - stops[i][1] + passatgersTren;

            // Si el numero de pasajeros que bajan en la primera estación es mayor que 0 muestra en el mensaje de error ya que en la primera estación solo puede subir gente y no bajar (tren vacío)
            if (stops[0][1] > 0){
                System.out.println("[ERROR] No passenger can get off at the first station!!");
            }
            // Si el nombre de pasajeros que bajan en cualquier estación es mayor al número de pasajeros en el tren mostramos el error.
            else if (stops[i][1] > passatgersTren) {
                int estacio = i + 1;
                System.out.println("[ERROR] Stop" + estacio + ": No more passengers can get off the train " + stops[i][0] + "  than there are!! " + passatgersTren + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    return passatgersTren;
}
```

Sin embargo el resultado que estoy devolviendo es 22 y no entiendo porqué. Además estoy testeando múltiples resultados de la siguiente forma:

```
class PAC1Ex3Test {
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void testFinalJourneyPassengers() {
        assertEquals(11, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{6, 0}, {8, 2}, {1, 2}}));
        assertEquals(19, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}, {8, 2}, {9, 5}, {3, 1}}));
        assertEquals(-1, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {3, 1}}));
        assertEquals(1, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}, {1, 6}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}}));
        assertEquals(-1, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{5, 1}, {1, 6}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}}));
        assertEquals(10, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{5, 0}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {10, 2}}));
        assertEquals(2, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{3, 0}, {2, 3}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}}));

        assertEquals(7, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}}));
        assertEquals(0, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}, {0, 7}}));
        assertEquals(7, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}, {7, 7}}));
        assertEquals(7, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}, {0, 0}}));
        assertEquals(0, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}));

        assertEquals(-1, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}, {0, 8}}));
        assertEquals(-1, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}, {7, 8}}));
    }
}
```

Cómo podría añadir una condición de que si el resultado no coincide con el esperado devuelva -1?

Comment: Para el caso de tu edición a la pregunta (uso de `assertEquals`) no sería necesario que uses sentencias `if` para mostrar errores durante la ejecución de tu programa. Deberías devolver `-1` siempre que el conteo de pasajeros sea negativo.

Comment: Lo qué no entiendo es la última prueba, entran 7 pasajeros y no baja ninguno, pero luego suben 7 pasajeros y bajan 8, pero se espera un `-1`, ¿podías explicar eso?

Comment: Creo que no lo estamos haciendo bien. Deberíamos seguir la prioridad de el transporte público en la vida real. Es decir, primer dejar salir antes de entrar. Primero contabilizar los que bajan y después los que suben. De hecho, ahora mismo estoy obteniendo también un error en assertEquals(1, PAC1Ex3.finalJourneyPassengers(new int[][]{{7, 0}, {1, 6}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}})); Obtengo un -1 en vez de 1.

Comment: Entiendo, edito la respuesta, a ver si alcanzamos ya la solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el resultado que te devuelve es debido al segundo `for`, no lo estás usando, pero se ejecuta 2 veces para cada estación, es decir:

Para `i = 0`, tienes que suben `6` y bajan `0` y el contador de pasajeros es `0`, por lo que para `j = 0` los pasajeros totales son `6` y para `j = 1` los pasajeros de la primera estación serán `12`.

Por lo tanto cuando `i = 2` y `j = 2` tendrás el doble de pasajeros.

Esto se arreglaría quitando el segundo `for`, podrías dejar así tu código:

```
public static int finalJourneyPassengers(int[][] stops) {
    // Inicializamos la variable pasajeros en el tren
    int passatgersTren = 0;

    // Recorremos la matriz donde i corresponde a la estación y j a las columnas (pasajeros que bajan o suben)
    for (int i=0; i < stops.length; i++) {
        if (stops[0][1] > 0){
            // Si el número de pasajeros que bajan en la primera estación es mayor que 0 muestra en el mensaje de error y devolvemos -1
            System.out.println("[ERROR] No passenger can get off at the first station!!");
            return -1;
        } else if (stops[i][1] > passatgersTren) {
            // Si el número de pasajeros que bajan en cualquier estación es mayor al número de pasajeros en el tren mostramos el error y devolvemos -1.
            int estacion = i + 1;
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Stop" + estacion + ": No more passengers can get off the train " + stops[i][0] + "  than there are!! " + passatgersTren + " ");
            return -1;
        } else {
            // Los pasajeros en el tren son los que suben - los que bajan.
            passatgersTren = stops[i][0] - stops[i][1] + passatgersTren;
        }
    }

    return passatgersTren;
}
```

**Edición**

Con la edición con las pruebas unitarias veo que no se interrumpe la ejecución en caso de que vayan a bajan más pasajeros de los que hay en el tren, esto podría provocar un error.
He modificado el comportamiento del incremento de los pasajeros que suben y el decremento de los que bajan.

Comment: como podría añadir la condición de que si el resultado no es el esperado devuelva -1? Estoy utilizando assertEquals para el testeo.

Comment: Haz la comprobación así: `assertEquals(11, finalJourneyPassengers(stops))`, si obtienes un valor que no sea 11 te dará error, no tienes que añadir código para implementar una prueba unitaria, la prueba debe ser trasparente para el código, en la variable `stops` le puedes pasar el array directamente. Para comprobar otros resultados tienes que hacer una prueba nueva por ejemplo: `[[6,0] [8,2] [1]]` y comprobar que sea `12`.

Comment: Profavor, dale un vistazo a la edición del post. Creo que debería añadir una condición ya que ahora mismo no estoy devolviendo un -1.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para que devuelvas un `-1` en caso de que se produzca un error, espero que así te funcione correctamente.

Comment: Ahora si funciona, muchas gracias! Buen trabajo :)

Comment: De nada, un placer poder ayudar.

Comment: podrías echarle un ojo a este post? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/488100/112550

Answer (score 1):

Estás declarando el iterador `j`, pero nunca lo usas. En este caso, no haría falta una segunda iteración. Puedes acceder al valor de los pasajeros que suben y bajan sin necesidad de iterar una segunda vez.

Por ejemplo:

```java
public static int finalJourneyPassengers(int[][] stops)
    {
        // Inicializamos la variable pasajeros en el tren
        int passatgersTren = 0;
        // Recorremos la matriz donde i corresponde a la estacion y j a las columnas (pasajeros que bajan o suben)
        for (int i=0; i < stops.length; i++)
        {
            // Los pasajeros en el tren son los que suben - los que bajan.
            passatgersTren = stops[i][0] - stops[i][1] + passatgersTren;
            // Si el numero de pasajeros que bajan en la primera estacion es mayor que 0 muestra en el mensaje de error ya que en la primera estación solo puede subir gente y no bajar (tren vacío)
            if (stops[0][1] > 0)
            {
                    System.out.println("[ERROR] No passenger can get off at the first station!!");
            }
            // Si el nombre de pasajeros que bajan en cualquier estación es mayor al nombre de pasajeros en el tren mostramos el error.
            else if (stops[i][1] > passatgersTren)
            {
                int estacio = i + 1;
                System.out.println("[ERROR] Stop" + estacio + ": No more passengers can get off the train " + stops[i][0] + "  than there are!! " + passatgersTren + " ");
            }
        }
    return passatgersTren;
    }
```

Claramente puedes observar que la lógica es la misma que tenías planteada, a excepción del bucle `for` anidado. Este bucle era la causa de el resultado doble, en vez de 11, estabas obteniendo 22, ya que estabas contando 2 veces la cantidad de pasajeros en el tren.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

**Edición**

De la edición de tu pregunta, entiendo que tu método o función debe devolver un valor positivo o cero cuando procesa listas válidas de subidas y bajadas de pasajeros en las paradas y debe devolver `-1` si la lista de paradas tiene valores no válidos.

Por ejemplo, una lista inválida sería aquella que indique que en la primera parada hay pasajeros que bajan del tren, siendo que el tren inicia el recorrido sin pasajeros.

En ese caso, sólo debes devolver el valor de pasajeros si éste es mayor o igual a cero, y para ello, la sentencia condicional has de hacerla al final del proceso, fuera de tu bucle `for`.

Por ejemplo:

```java
public static int finalJourneyPassengers(int[][] stops)
    {
        // Inicializamos la variable pasajeros en el tren
        int passatgersTren = 0;
        // Recorremos la matriz donde i corresponde a la estacion y j a las columnas (pasajeros que bajan o suben)
        for (int i=0; i < stops.length; i++)
        {
            // Los pasajeros en el tren son los que suben - los que bajan.
            passatgersTren = stops[i][0] - stops[i][1] + passatgersTren;
        }
    // aquí analizamos el valor calculado, si es negativo devolvemos -1
    if(passatgersTren < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    // en caso que el valor calculado sea mayor o igual a cero se devuelve el valor calculado
    return passatgersTren;
    }
```

De esta forma tu función cumple con las especificaciones.

Comment: Estoy usando assertEquals para validar el resultado con testeo. Como podria añadir la condición de que si el resultado no es el esperado devuelva -1?