# Ordenar un vector de números sin usar el método sort() e imprimir su posición

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en Java. Estoy intentando ordenar un conjunto de números correspondientes a las notas de estudiantes de mayor a menor. Por el momento, he hecho lo siguiente:

```
public static void sortAverageGradesAndShowIndices(double[] averageNotes) {
    double doubleNotes, aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < averageNotes.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < averageNotes.length - 1; j++) {
            // Si el numero actual es mayor al siguiente
            if(averageNotes[j] > averageNotes[j + 1]) {
                // Intercambiamos numeros
                aux = averageNotes[j];
                averageNotes[j] = averageNotes[j + 1];
                averageNotes[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    // Ordenamos de mayor a menor
    for (int i = (averageNotes.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%.1f (%d)",averageNotes[i],i));
    }
}
```

Al mismo tiempo, se me pide pasar un test de resultados. El test es el siguiente:

```
void testSortAverageNotesAndShowIndices() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStreamCaptor = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outputStreamCaptor));
    PAC1Ex3.sortAverageGradesAndShowIndices(new double[] {4.2, 8.1, 9.4, 6.1, 4.7, 6.4, 6.0, 7.7});
    assertEquals("9.4 (2)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "8.1 (1)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "7.7 (7)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "6.4 (5)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "6.1 (3)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "6.0 (6)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "4.7 (4)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "4.2 (0)", outputStreamCaptor.toString().trim());

    outputStreamCaptor = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outputStreamCaptor));
    PAC1Ex3.sortAverageGradesAndShowIndices(new double[] {6.6, 7.9, 8.9, 9.6, 7.3, 6.5, 4.0});
    assertEquals("9.6 (3)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "8.9 (2)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "7.9 (1)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "7.3 (4)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "6.6 (0)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "6.5 (5)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "4.0 (6)", outputStreamCaptor.toString().trim());

    outputStreamCaptor = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outputStreamCaptor));
    PAC1Ex3.sortAverageGradesAndShowIndices(new double[] {7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0});
    assertEquals("9.0 (4)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "8.5 (3)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "8.0 (2)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "7.5 (1)" + System.lineSeparator()
            + "7.0 (0)", outputStreamCaptor.toString().trim());
}
```

La ordenación se está realizando de forma correcta pero **la recuperación del índice que ocupa el número en el vector original no**. A continuación muestro el output:

```
9,4 (7)
8,1 (6)
7,7 (5)
6,4 (4)
6,1 (3)
6,0 (2)
4,7 (1)
4,2 (0)
```

Por ejemplo, el primer test supone que el vector a tratar es el siguiente: `{4.2, 8.1, 9.4, 6.1, 4.7, 6.4, 6.0, 7.7}`, la salida debería ser algo como:

```
"9.4 (2)"
"8.1 (1)"
"7.7 (7)"
"6.4 (5)"
"6.1 (3)"
"6.0 (6)"
"4.7 (4)"
"4.2 (0)"
```

Comment: Recuerda comentar las respuestas o aceptar la que te satisfaga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardar el estado inicial del vector en un vector auxiliar y, una vez finalice la ordenación del vector, comprobar la posición inicial de cada uno de los elementos en el vector ya ordenado usando el vector auxiliar.

```
public static void sortAverageGradesAndShowIndices(double[] averageNotes) {
    double[] initialAverageNotes = averageNotes;
    double doubleNotes, aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < averageNotes.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < averageNotes.length - 1; j++) {
            // Si el numero actual es mayor al siguiente
            if(averageNotes[j] > averageNotes[j + 1]) {
                // Intercambiamos numeros
                aux = averageNotes[j];
                averageNotes[j] = averageNotes[j + 1];
                averageNotes[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    // Mostramos el orden original en el vector ordenado
    for (int i = 0; i < initialAverageNotes.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < averageNotes.length - 1; j++) {
            if (initialAverageNotes[i] == averageNotes[j]) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%.1f (%d)", averageNotes[j], i));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Claramente, según lo que publicas y tu necesidad, todo está bien algorítmicamente. Lo único que te falta es al momento de imprimir los valores del array. Tienes que imprimir un String con el valor del índice y su índice, de tal forma que quedaría algo así:

```
for (int i=(averageNotes.length-1); i>=0;i--){
    System.out.println(String.format("%.1f (%d)",averageNotes[i],i));
}
```

Comment: No es del todo así. He modificado el post para que veas la salida que estoy obteniendo. Ahora mismo estoy colocando la posición del número en el vector ordenado. Sin embargo, debería colocar la posición del número en el vector original (sin ordenar). Para ello había pensado en crear un nuevo vector y con el vector final buscar la posición que el número ocupa en este nuevo vector. No sé cómo hacerlo.